# WebStorm module not installed webpack error

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, nuxt.js

```
import CustomWidget from '@/components/widgets/CustomWidget';
```

When I import a Vue component. The Vue component works and all, but when I use `@` it cannot resolve the declaration (it gives me cannot find declaration to go to).

I have this problem on Vue application and nuxt applications.

I am using WebStorm 2018.2.2

Answer (score 10):

For Vue-cli 3.x, you have to specify `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js` as **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack** value.
Resolving webpack aliases in Nuxt projects doesn't currently work, please follow [WEB-32614](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32614) for updates